# Webpack module source code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I need to save the code of a es6 code module and dump it.
So ideally what I would need is something like:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
// this function get the source code of the
// module I am running in 
function getMyModuleSourceCode = {
  ...
}

class DemoComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const myCode = getMyModuleSourceCode();
        processMySourceCode(myCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is, can you be more precise? At which point do you want to save the code of an ES6 module? How does webpack come into play here?

Comment: I updated the text. My guess is that only by using webpack it is possibile in the render function to know the code of the module.

Comment: So you want to include the source code of another module (not the compiled javascript) into the DemoComponent?

Comment: I want the source code of the current module (not the compiled javascript) so that in the DemoComponent I can make stats / show on video dump on console / whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the module is in a different file, you can import twice, once normally to run code, once with the [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader) to just pull in the file verbatim.

```
import module from './module'; //compiled code
import moduleSource from '!!raw!./module'; //source as text
```

The `!!` is necessary to override the existing loaders if you are just testing for `.js` extensions.

Comment: Wao , I wasted like 4 hours of my life searching for this, couldn't find any information about the override `!!` in the `raw-loader` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) in webpack and then require whatever file you need in your function:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
// this function get the source code of the
// module I am running in 
function getMyModuleSourceCode = {
    return require('!!file!./path/to/module.js');
}

class DemoComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const myCode = getMyModuleSourceCode();
        processMySourceCode(myCode);
    }
}
```